# How can I get my program to stop looping after a user correctly guessed the hangman in under 18 tries?

Tags: java, arrays, game-development, do-while

I made a simple hangman game in java, and in my do while loop, I wanted the loop to stop when the user either guessed the word correctly in under 18 tries, or if the word wasnt correctly guessed in 18 tries. however, if my word has been guessed before the 18 attempts are up, the loop keeps on running until the 18 tries have been used up. what can I do to fix this please?

this is my main program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hangman{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        hangmanMethods m = new hangmanMethods();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String[]words = new String[20];
        String name;
        char guess;
        int option;
        boolean checkifcorrect;
        System.out.println("Welcome to hangman! \nWhat is your name?");
        name=sc.nextLine();

        if (name.equals("diane"))
            System.out.println("hello diane. happy birthday :)");
        else System.out.println("hello " +name);
        System.out.println("please press 1 to start playing");
        option=sc.nextInt();
        switch(option){
            case 1: m.hangmanwords();
                String randomword = m.generateword();
                int numletters = m.countletters(randomword);

                System.out.println("lets play hangman. a random word has been generated and has " +numletters+ " letters. you have 18 guesses. choose a letter to start.");

                char[] guessedLetters = new char[numletters];
                for (int i = 0; i < numletters; i++) {
                    guessedLetters[i] = '_';
                }

                System.out.println(guessedLetters);
                int maxattempts = 18;
                int attempts = 0;

                do{
                    for (int i = 0; i <18; i++) {
                        guess = sc.next().charAt(0);
                        boolean correct = false;

                        for (int j = 0; j < numletters; j++) {
                            if (randomword.charAt(j) == guess) {
                                guessedLetters[j] = guess;
                                correct = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (correct == true) {
                            System.out.println("correct guess! well done");
                            System.out.println(guessedLetters);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("incorrect guess :((((");
                        }
                        attempts++;
                    }
                    
                    checkifcorrect = m.checking(numletters, randomword, guessedLetters);
                }while (attempts<maxattempts || !checkifcorrect );
                
                if (attempts<maxattempts && checkifcorrect==true )
                    System.out.println("yayyyy you got the word ♥♥♥♥"+" would you like to play again? input 1 to continue or 2 to exit :)");
                else System.out.println("you used up all of your guesses :(( the word was " +randomword+ ". would you like to play again? press 1 to continue or 2 to exit");
                option=sc.nextInt();
                break; 
            case 2: System.out.println("thanks for playing");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my methods class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hangmanMethods{
    private String[]words = new String[20];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    public void setArray (String[] numbers) {
        this.words = words;
    }  

    public String[] getArray () {
        return words;
    }

    public void hangmanwords(){   
        //initialising the words 
        words[0]= "sushi";
        words[1]= "korea";
        words[2]= "computing";
        words[3]= "caty";
        words[4]= "thomas";
        words[5]= "winter";
        words[6]= "chocolate";
        words[7]= "kimchi";
        words[8]= "rain";
        words[9]= "plants";
        words[10]= "kinnie";
        words[11]= "strawberries";
        words[12]= "raptures";
        words[13]= "pacman";
        words[14]= "coldplay";
        words[15]= "asos";
        words[16]= "shopping";
        words[17]= "tkmaxx";
        words[18]= "flamingo";
        words[19]= "blue";

    }

    public String generateword() {
        int randomlocation = (int) (Math.random() * 19); 
        String randomWord = words[randomlocation];
        return randomWord;
    }

    public int countletters(String word) {
        return word.length();
    }

    public boolean checking (int numletters, String randomword, char[] guessedLetters) {
        boolean checkcorrect = true;
        for( int i = 0; i<numletters; i++){
            if (guessedLetters[i] != randomword.charAt(i))
                checkcorrect = false;

            break;}
        return checkcorrect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually two fold.
First, `do while` block first executes the entire body of `do` statement and then checks for the condition in the `while` statement. There is `for` loop inside the `do` block, which will run to its entirety and then the `while` loop's condition will be evaluated. Because of this `for` loop you are unable to exit the game when user has guessed the word correctly.
Second, the exit condition in while block is also incorrect. It will continue to run until both the conditions, `attempts<maxattempts` and `!checkIfCorrect` evaluates to false. What you want is to exit the block once either one of the condition fails. Basically it should be replaced with `attempts < maxattempts && !checkifcorrect`
Here's the modified `do while` block of code

```
do {
    guess = sc.next().charAt(0);
    boolean correct = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < numletters; j++) {
        if (randomword.charAt(j) == guess) {
            guessedLetters[j] = guess;
            correct = true;
        }
    }
    if (correct == true) {
        System.out.println("correct guess! well done");
        System.out.println(guessedLetters);
    } else {
        System.out.println("incorrect guess :((((");
    }
    attempts++;

    checkifcorrect = m.checking(numletters, randomword, guessedLetters);
} while (attempts < maxattempts && !checkifcorrect);
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping. however, with this block of code, the program tells the user they have gotten the whole word correct when they have guessed the first letter of the word, even if there are still unguessed letters